# Debugging via Visual Studio Code tizentv Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-studio, tizen-tv

I can debug my app in Tizen Studio, however, the web inspector does not work when debugging the app in Visual Studio Code via tizentv extension.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tizensdk.tizentv

The app runs on the connected TV.

The properties `“type”: “tizentv”` and `“targetIp”: “…”` are not recognized.

The documentation seems to be outdated.

Anyone succeeded in debugging apps via Visual Studio Code tizentv extension?

Comment: Did you find an issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I tested it on tizentv (version 1.3.3)

Set target IP

Run `Tizen TV: Set Target Device Address` command.

OR write "tizentv.targetDeviceAddress" in setting.json

```
 - File > Preferences > User Settings or Code > Preferences > User Settings
```

Run Command

1. `Tizen TV: Build Signed Package` (it create .wgt file from your App)
2. `Tizen TV: Debug Application`

- Select `Debug On TV`

The app runs on the connected TV.

then tizentv will execute chrome browser with chrome inspector.